# How can I get random displayed images and background colours to match

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to randomly change the background colour between 4 different colours on each page visit but i also want the image that displayed on the page to match the background

For example, Red background with red.jpg, or Blue background with blue.jpg

The issue I'm having is that they are both being randomised separately and are not matching.

This is what I'm using

```
const imageElement = document.getElementById('random-image');
const imageSources = [  'red.jpg',  'orange.jpg',  'yellow.jpg',  'green.jpg',];
const backgroundColors = [  'red',  'orange',  'yellow',  'green',];

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function setRandomImage() {
  const randomIndex = getRandomInt(imageSources.length);
   imageElement.src = imageSources[randomIndex];
}

function setRandomBackgroundColor() {
  const randomIndex = getRandomInt(backgroundColors.length);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColors[randomIndex];
}

setRandomImage();
setRandomBackgroundColor();
```

Comment: Why not just combine the functions so that they both use the same index?

Comment: Can you explain, im fairly new to javascript

Comment: Generate only one random index and/or use one array of objects containing both a name and a color.

Answer (score 1):

### Original Solution

There are definitely other ways of doing this (such as using an array of objects for the background and color), but based on the code provided, here is a simple way of combining the two functions to use the same `randomIndex` value.

```
const imageElement = document.getElementById('random-image');
const imageSources = [  'red.jpg',  'orange.jpg',  'yellow.jpg',  'green.jpg',];
const backgroundColors = [  'red',  'orange',  'yellow',  'green',];

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function setRandomImageAndBackground() {
  const randomIndex = getRandomInt(imageSources.length);
   imageElement.src = imageSources[randomIndex];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColors[randomIndex];
}

setRandomImageAndBackground();
```

### Alternative Solution

Another way to use only one `randomIndex` value is to declare the `randomIndex` outside of any functions. Because the index seems to only need to be declared once when the page loads, this should work just fine for your use-case.

You could still combine both functions using this method, but declaring the `randomIndex` outside of any functions allows you to use that value anywhere as it becomes a **global** variable. So if for some reason you *need* the functions to be separate, this would allow you to do that.

```
const imageElement = document.getElementById('random-image');
const imageSources = [  'red.jpg',  'orange.jpg',  'yellow.jpg',  'green.jpg',];
const backgroundColors = [  'red',  'orange',  'yellow',  'green',];
const randomIndex = getRandomInt(imageSources.length);

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function setRandomImage() {
   imageElement.src = imageSources[randomIndex];
}

function setRandomBackgroundColor() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColors[randomIndex];
}

setRandomImage();
setRandomBackgroundColor();
```

### Object-based Solution

Both the above solutions use two separate arrays for the images and colors, which works fine as long as you make sure both arrays are the same length. Sometimes that can be difficult to maintain depending on how many items are in these arrays and so I prefer to use arrays of objects when dealing with multiple arrays that are meant to be linked/related.

```
const imageElement = document.getElementById('random-image'),
imagesAndColors = [
  { img: 'red.jpg', background: 'red' },
  { img: 'orange.jpg', background: 'orange' },
  { img: 'yellow.jpg', background: 'yellow' },
  { img: 'green.jpg', background: 'green' },
]

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function setRandomImageAndBackground() {
  const randomIndex = getRandomInt(imagesAndColors.length)
  imageElement.src = imagesAndColors[randomIndex].img
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = imagesAndColors[randomIndex].background
}

setRandomImageAndBackground()
```

This is similar to the original idea of combining the two functions, however the main idea is that adding/removing images and background colors from your array will be easier.

Comment: Ah ok. I see what you mean. Thanks a lot for that. much appreciated